# Oracle PL/SQL update based on values calculated from multiple tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to write a PL/SQL that sums up the value from 2 tables and update the value to another table.

I have the following tables: ONLINE_SALES, STORE_SALES, TOTAL_SALES

Assume the tables are structured like this:

```
ONLINE_SALES: OS_ID, STORE_ID, SEQ, ITEM_NAME, PRICE, PURCHASED_DATE

STORE_SALES: SS_ID, STORE_ID, SEQ, ITEM_NAME, PRICE, PURCHASED_DATE

TOTAL_SALES: STORE_ID, YEAR, TOTAL_INCOME
```

I want to write a PL/SQL that runs monthly and sums up the income (values in PRICE field) made in the month from both ONLINE_SALES and STORE_SALES of each store (identified by STORE_ID) and add the value to record in TOTAL_SALES with relative year.

My idea is to first filter the record by PURCHASED_DATE from both table with a SELECT, loop through all selected rows and sum to a variable and at last update the result with an UPDATE. But I am stuck in the first step since I found that I cannot use SELECT and only SELECT INTO is available.

Any ideas on how such PL/SQL can be written?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure? This sounds as if it can easily be done using a MERGE statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - probably because the assignment asks for a PL/SQL solution. And actually a MERGE solution is not obvious.

Answer (score 0):

This solution assumes your stored procedure takes a DATE which it uses to identify the month and the year which is being totalled. Perhaps your assignment is expecting a different form of input? No worries. The deriving the values of year and date range is separate from the main process, so it is easy to swap in some different logic.

The loop uses an explicit cursor with the FOR UPDATE syntax. This locks the TOTAL_SALES table, which means you are guaranteed to be able to update all the rows.

```sql
create or replace calc_total_sales 
    ( p_month in date )
is
     cursor c_tot_sales (p_year number) is
          select * from total_sales    
          where year = p_year
          for update of total_income;
     c_tot_sales c_tot_sales%rowtype;

     l_os_sales number;
     l_ss_sales number;

     l_year number;
     1_first_day date;
     1_last_day date;

begin

    l_year      := to_number( to_char( p_month, 'yyyy') );
    l_first_day := trunc( p_month, 'mm');
    l_last_day  := last_day( p_month);

    open c_tot_sales( l_year );

    loop

        fetch c_tot_sales into r_tot_sales;
        exit when c_tot_sales%not found;

        select sum(price)
        into l_os_sales
        from online_sales 
        where store_id = r_tot_sales.store_id
        and   purchased_date >= l_first_day
        and   purchased_date <= l_last_day;

        select sum(price)
        into l_ss_sales
        from store_sales 
        where store_id = r_tot_sales.store_id
        and   purchased_date >= l_first_day
        and   purchased_date <= l_last_day;

        update total_sales
        set total_income = total_income + nvl(l_ss_sales,0) + nvl(l_os_sales,0)
        where current of c_total_sales;

    end loop;

    close c_tot_sales;

    commit;

end;
/
```